# How to get artist name form last.fm api

Tags: php, json, api, last.fm

I want to get artist name from last.fm api
*HEre is a code*

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&limit=56&api_key=MYAPIKEY&format=json');
            $jsonData = json_decode($jsonData, true);
foreach ($jsonData['tracks']['track'] as $track) {
                $title = $track['name'];
                $image = $track['image'][3]['#text'];
                echo '<div id="track_short"><div class="track_short">
                <a href="http://'.$SiteUrl.'/mp3-download-'.cano($title).'/" ><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$title.'">
                <div class="description"><p class="description_content">'.$title.'</p>
                </div></a></div></div>';
}
```

**Example of API data**

```
{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Sorry","duration":"0","playcount":"1931615","listeners":"193074","mbid":"","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Justin+Bieber/_/Sorry","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Justin Bieber","mbid":"e0140a67-e4d1-4f13-8a01-364355bee46e","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Justin+Bieber"},"image":[{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"extralarge"}]}],"@attr":{"page":"1","perPage":"1","totalPages":"253572626","total":"253572626"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cool thanks i have correct
from : `$phpArtist = $phpJson['tracks']['track'][0]['artist'];`
to : `$Artist = $track['artist']['name'];`
and its working, thanks

Comment: Please do not add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, you should accept the answer that solved your problem. When you have enough reputation, you can also [upvote helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [award a bounty to helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method:

```
$json = '{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Sorry","duration":"0","playcount":"1931615","listeners":"193074","mbid":"","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Justin+Bieber/_/Sorry","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Justin Bieber","mbid":"e0140a67-e4d1-4f13-8a01-364355bee46e","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Justin+Bieber"},"image":[{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/d5af34cbc048b190fc7369acdcf8655b.png","size":"extralarge"}]}],"@attr":{"page":"1","perPage":"1","totalPages":"253572626","total":"253572626"}}}';
$phpJson = json_decode($json, true, 10); //4 is the depth of the JSON string, but you can make this a big number and it will still work
$phpArtist = $phpJson['tracks']['track'][0]['artist']['name'];
```

Let me know if that works, or if the php needs to get tweaked, I don't have a PHP client up right now.